# React-router-dom: Nested routes is not working but routes instead from within the root component App

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-router-component

I am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@marxlow/simple-nested-routes-with-layouts-in-react-router-v4-59b8b63a1184) to implement Nested routing.
Here's the relevant code:

> App.js

```
   <PrivateRoute
                exact
                name="Home"
                path="/home"
                component={DefaultLayout}
              />
```

> DefaultLayout.js

```
const Users = React.lazy(() => import("../../views/Users/Users"));

          <Route path="/home/users" component={Users} />
```

> PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      )
    }
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

So as you may have guessed, I am protecting the **/home** route with the **PrivateRoute** component.
The **/home** routes is associated with **DefaultLayout** component.
The **DefaultLayout** component contains a **NestedRoute** that is **/home/users** which leads to the component **Users**.

The private route functions properly and it routes the user after he logs-in to the default layout:
[image]
However when I click on a button that routes me to **/home/users**, I get this blank screen:
[image]
Any idea what I've done wrong?
**EDIT 1**: When I add this to App.js:

```
   const Users = React.lazy(() => import("../../views/Users/Users"));

              <Route path="/home/users" component={Users} />
```

I do get routed to the **Users** component. However, not as a **nested route** but as a component in the **root routes**. In other words, the **Users** component **does not appear** inside the **defaultLayout** component but appears as a **root component**. I hope that makes sense. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

**EDIT 1 Conclusion:** The **Nested routing** implementation doesn't work. The app still routes from inside **App.js** instead from inside **DefaultLayout.js**.
**EDIT 2:** I realized that even without the **PrivateRoute** component and using the normal **Route** component, the **nested routing** still doesn't work:

```
      <Route exact path="/home" name="Home" component={DefaultLayout} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to remove the `exact` prop from your `Home` `Route`:

```
<Route path="/home" name="Home" component={DefaultLayout} />
```

With `exact`, your `DefaultLayout` component will only be rendered when the url is *exactly* `/home`. Since `/home/users` isn't equal to `/home`, when you navigate to `/home/users`, neither your `DefaultLayout` component nor the nested `Users` route will be rendered.

Here are the docs that describe the `exact` prop: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#exact-bool

Comment: Hey, even if I remove exact I still get a blank screen when I enter /home/users

Comment: The problem is that react-router-dom routes from inside App.js instead of handing the routing to the DefaultLayout component

Comment: Hmm maybe it would help to see more of your `DefaultLayout` component code

Comment: Hey Matt, actually that solved my problem thank you